# Show that $d(\omega)|_{U} = 0$

Tags: smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

Suppose the map $d : \Omega^*(M) \rightarrow \Omega^*(M)$ (where $\Omega^*(M)$ is the space of differential forms on a smooth manifold $M$) is an *antiderivation* and $\omega \in \Omega^*(M)$ such that $\omega|_{U} = 0$ for some open subset $U \subseteq M $.

Antiderivation on a graded algebra $A = \bigoplus_{k=0}^{\infty} A^k$ is a $\mathbb{R}$ linear map $D : A \rightarrow A$ such that $D(\omega. \tau) = (D \omega). \tau + (-1)^k \omega . D \tau $ ,  where $\omega \in A^k $ and $\tau \in A^l$.

Show that $d(\omega)|_{U} = 0$.

Any help with this..

Comment: how do you define antiderivative of differential form?

Comment: @Ben I have edited and included the definition in the question.

Comment: @Ben: There are no antiderivatives. It's just a skew-derivation like the usual exterior derivative.

Comment: You can prove that if $\phi = 0$ everywhere, then $d\phi = 0$. Now use a partition of unity argument. Note that $\omega = 0$ on a closed set $C$ containing $U$. Choose $f$ smooth with $f|_U = 1$ and $f=0$ on $\overline{M-C}$. Consider $\phi=f\omega$.

Comment: Sorry but I still don't get this.

Comment: @Dark_Knight: Can you be more specific? (Also, you need to ping me if you expect me to see you've responded.) I assume you know basics about manifolds (such as bump functions and partitions of unity subordinate to an open cover); if not, go read about them!